# CSS: 2-column table, how to make one column as small as possible but no wrap and the other as big as possible?

Tags: html, css

I have a two column table (width: 100%).
I want the first column to be as small as possible, but the text should not be wrapped. The other column should be as big as possible.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Some example text:</td>
        <td><input type=text/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
td:first-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1vtendt/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply two CSS rules to your first cell:

```
white-space: nowrap;
width: 1%;
```

The first one prevents text from wrapping, the second one makes cell expanding from 1% width to the width of the content.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zm6L8gzu/2/

Comment: Should that not be `width` in stead of `min-width`. Your demo is not working on chrome/mac, while the `width` is: http://jsfiddle.net/zm6L8gzu/1/

Comment: You're right, I fixed it. I'm kinda surprised Firefox behaves differently about this.